# Save rails time_select as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, time

I have a string field in my databse

```
class CreateMHolidays < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :m_holidays do |t|
      t.string :open_schedule, :limit => 50
    end
  end
end
```

I am using [`time_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_select) to get the value for `open_schedule` field.

```
<%= f.time_select :open_schedule, {minute_step: 01, include_blank: true,:default =>{:hour => '00', :minute => '00'},:ignore_date => true}, {:class => 'form-control'} %>
```

In my controller I try

```
@m_holidays = MHoliday.new(m_holiday_params)

@open_schedule_hrs = (params[:m_holidays]['open_schedule(4i)']).to_s
@open_schedule_mns = (params[:m_holidays]['open_schedule(5i)']).to_s
@m_holidays.open_schedule = @open_schedule_hrs + ':' + @open_schedule_mns
```

But when I try to save the record I am getting

> ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors (1 error(s) on assignment
>   of multiparameter attributes [error on assignment [3, 3] to
>   open_schedule (Missing Parameter - open_schedule(1))])

This is the first time I am using `time_select` and I must use it with a string field rather than `:time`. How to go about this? Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the [ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/MultiparameterAssignmentErrors.html) because of the mass parameter assignment on the line `@m_holidays = MHoliday.new(m_holiday_params)`. This might be due to `m_holiday_params` containing parameters that your `MHoliday` model doesn't know what to do with.

Try filtering out everything related to the `open_schedule` input from `m_holiday_params`. If you have an `m_holiday_params` method like this:

```
def m_holiday_params
  params.require(:m_holiday).permit('open_schedule(4i)', 'open_schedule(5i)', ...)
end
```

then omit the `open_schedule` parameters:

```
def m_holiday_params
  params.require(:m_holiday).permit(...)
end
```

Then you can manually set up your `open_schedule` string, as you've already done.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't get what exactly u meant by "filtering out everything related to the `open_schedule` input from `m_holiday_params`". could you please elaborate ??

Comment: well my `m_holiday` params is `params.require(:m_holiday).permit(:open_schedule,...)`

Comment: Removing `:open_schedule` should do it.

Comment: thant worked like a charm...... but wouldn't this create problems when updating the record ??

Comment: It'll work fine, you just need to manually set the `open_schedule` attribute in each action that creates/updates an `MHoliday` record, like you did in your original question.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :-)